# Angular 6 cannot create a CanvasRenderingContext2D

Tags: html, angular

i'm currently working with Angular 6 and angular-charts, i'm trying to use a gradient to color a bar chart, but the angular-cli shows a compilation error:

```
error TS1068: Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.
src/app/home/client/employee-home/employee-home.component.ts(38,6): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
src/app/home/client/employee-home/employee-home.component.ts(38,40): error TS1109: Expression expected.
src/app/home/client/employee-home/employee-home.component.ts(55,17): error TS1005: ';' expected.
src/app/home/client/employee-home/employee-home.component.ts(57,14): error TS1005: ';' expected.
src/app/home/client/employee-home/employee-home.component.ts(60,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
```

in this line of code:

```
let ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D =  this.canvasRef.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
```

My html:

```
   <canvas #canvas id="canvas" baseChart class="chart" [datasets]="barChartData" [labels]="barChartLabels" [options]="barChartOptions" [colors]="barChartColors" [legend]="barChartLegend" [chartType]="barChartType" (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)" (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
```

typescript:

```
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild,ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-home',
  templateUrl: './employee-home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('canvas') canvasRef: ElementRef;

public barChartOptions: any = {
      scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false

    };

     public barChartLabels: string[] = ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio'];

     public barChartType = 'bar';
     public barChartLegend = false;

     public barChartData: any[] = [
      { data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Horas extra' }
    ];

  let ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D =  this.canvasRef.nativeElement.getContext('2d');



var gradientStroke = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 200, 0, 100)

gradientStroke.addColorStop(0,"rgba(0,0,240,0.6)" );
gradientStroke.addColorStop(0.7, "rgba(255, 255, 51,0.5)");
gradientStroke.addColorStop(1, "rgba(248,64,0,0.6)");

     public barChartColors: Array<any> = [


      {

        backgroundColor: ["red", "orange", "green", "blue", "yellow", "purple"], 
        borderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
        pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
        pointBorderColor: '#fff',
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
        pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
      }

    ];



  constructor() { };

  ngOnInit() {
  };

}
```

i tried a fews solutions posted in this forums but no results.
How i can create a gradient to use it later?

Comment: Why do you need to use the canvas to make a gradient? you could just use css, and switch out the classes as needed...

Comment: Could you maybe upload your example to some website such as Plunkr? Would be easier to read + has line numbers.